# Неправильное отображение RGB цвета на ноутбуке hp

Tags: python, pillow, цвета

Пытаюсь написать бота на Python для авто изучения мода таумкрафт. Столкнулся с проблемой, что именно у меня программа по обнаружению цвета (colorPix) показывает другие оттенки красного цвета:

**Как показывает у меня:**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

ColorPix говорит, что это оттенок (216, 1, 5)

**Как показывает у моего друга:**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

colorPix показывает в ЭТОЙ же точке оттенок (222, 0, 5)

Так же, я взял другой ноутбук hp (Модель на год раньше моего) и программа colorPix показала оттенок (222, 0, 5).

Думаю, что у меня на ноутбуке, что-то не так с цветокоррекцией. Почитал посты в интернете, но решение не нашёл.
Помогите это исправить пожалуйста.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А зачем вам такая точность? Цветопередача зависит от настроек ОС, драйверов, марки монитора. Легче поставить в программе значения +- 10-20% для ловли определенного цвета.

Comment: Программу я пишу не один и если мой друг скинет мне код с его RGB цветами, то моя программа просто не найдёт нужный ей аспект ибо у меня RGB воспринимается по другому

Comment: @СергейКох А как можно реализовать  +- 10% для ловли определённого цвета?

Comment: Для начала можно взять диапазоны (210-230, 0-20, 0-20)

Comment: Можно посмотреть на граничные результаты https://www.w3schools.com/colors/colors_picker.asp#:~:text=RGB%20(Red%2C%20Green%2C%20Blue)

Comment: @СергейКох Я добавил фото выше. Я что-то совсем не пойму, а как меня добавить такой диапазон, если у меня для каждого Аспекта свой цвет RGB.

Comment: Скорее всего вы какие-нибудь соседние точки смотрите, чуть отличающиеся. А вообще если это реальная проблема, я бы просто поделил нацело каждую компоненту, например, на 24 - вот вам и округление.